# How do I handle user registration/membership in ASP.Net MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

Any recommended links, or tutorials on the subject?

How do I handle user registration and logged in status of users using my website? Is there something like ASP.Net membership (webforms) for the MVC flavor?

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET Membership API is accessible whether you're using web forms or MVC. You should be able to write your own login pages, etc. and then use the Membership classes to authenticate, create authentication tokens, assign users to roles, etc.

Having said that, there's a [starter pack](https://github.com/TroyGoode/MembershipStarterKit) out there for MVC.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion use self made membership system is best as i known. it's easy to customize and can be implemented in other project as same you done in your current project.

you can make custom authentication and you can implemented them in all project you have. the pros of this concept is that you can use authenticate the user in directory or subdomain without making them user again.

like i already have user of Stackoverflow.com then if i wish i can use them in user.stackoverflow.com and stackoverflow.com/user [user is a another project hosted in the project as directory bases]

Comment: I think this is bad general advice, because it's easy to get things wrong with security when doing it yourself. The framework will have had more security analysis done than something you come up with yourself.